# URL found in auth.gsp - beginner

Tags: grails

I need to know the following. I copied the following code from [auth.gsp](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp).  I need to know what:

1.) I need to know what '${postUrl}' means?

2.) I did copy this code and paste it in another GSP called index.gsp, but the page didn't login successfully.

```
<form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id="loginForm" name="loginForm" autocomplete='off'>
    <div class="sign-in">

    <h1><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.signin'/></h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="username"><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.username'/></label></td>
            <td><input name="j_username" id="username" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password"><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.password'/></label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="password" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="${rememberMeParameter}" id="remember_me" checked="checked" />
                <label for='remember_me'><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.rememberme'/></label> |
                <span class="forgot-link">
                    <g:link controller='register' action='forgotPassword'><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.forgotPassword'/></g:link>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <s2ui:linkButton elementId='register' controller='register' messageCode='spring.security.ui.login.register'/>
                <s2ui:submitButton elementId='loginButton' form='loginForm' messageCode='spring.security.ui.login.login'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring security work on filters. If you print `postUrl` in your gsp file then it looks like `/myApp/j_spring_security_check`, only `/j_spring_security_check` URL is processed by Spring Security filter.

If you past auth.gap and not sending this url then cannot login. Change your gsp slightly to make this run, replace `${postUrl}` with `${createLink(uri: '/j_spring_security_check')}`.